# Looking for the fastest way to check if an executable file is still running using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a codes that checks if an executable file is still running or not, but the problem is I find it quite slow when checking if the executable file is running or not. Is there a fastest way to do it?

```
 Public Function IsExeRunning(sExeName As String, Optional sComputer As 
 String = ".") As Boolean
     On Error GoTo Error_Handler
     Dim objProcesses    As Object

Set objProcesses = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & sComputer & "\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name  like '" & sExeName & "'") ' = '" & sExeName & "'")
If objProcesses.Count <> 0 Then IsExeRunning = True

Error_Handler_Exit:
     On Error Resume Next
     Set objProcesses = Nothing
     Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occured." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Error Number: IsExeRunning" & vbCrLf & _
        "Error Description: " & Err.Description, _
        vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
     Resume Error_Handler_Exit
 End Function
```

Comment: If the code is running but you feel there can be an improvement, then consider posting it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. It's of topic on here.

Answer (score 0):

This might be not working exactly as you are expecting as the like query isn't quite implemented correctly. I've fixed this and added a few optimizations, mainly reducing the number of returned query terms, adding an exact match method, and added a caching method to store a reference to the computer prior to the query.

```
Option Explicit

'Function averages 0.03 seconds on my machine
Public Function IsExeRunning(sExeName As String, _
                             Optional sComputer As String = ".", _
                             Optional ExactMatch As Boolean = False) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Static Computer As Object
    Dim Process     As Object
    Dim SearchQuery As String
    IsExeRunning = False

    'Cache Computer reference
    If Computer Is Nothing Or sComputer <> "." Then Set Computer = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    'Build query
    If ExactMatch Then
        SearchQuery = "SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" & sExeName & "'"
    Else
        SearchQuery = "SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name like '%" & sExeName & "%'"
    End If

    Set Process = Computer.ExecQuery(SearchQuery)
    If Process Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If Process.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    IsExeRunning = True

Error_Handler_Exit:
     Exit Function

Error_Handler:
     Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function

Sub TestRunner()
    Dim t As Single
    t = Timer
    Debug.Print "Function returns " & IsExeRunning("Excel", ".", False) & " took: " & Timer - t & " seconds"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thank you very much for your answer. I already fixed the problem by creating a dll file which will be reference to Excel VBA.